# Navigate to another page to a specific section in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, href

I have two different page

about.vue

```
<template>
 <div>
  <a class="headers" href="javascript:document.getElementById('steps').scrollIntoView(true);">Availability
  </a>
 </div>
</template>
```

home.vue

```
<template>
 <div>
  <p>This is the home page</p>
  <Services id="services"></Services>
  <Steps id="steps"></Steps>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Steps from 'views/home/steps.vue';
  import Services from 'views/home/services.vue';
  export default {
   components: {
    Services,
    Steps
   },
  }
</script>
```

I have a link on about page where when I click it should take me to the steps sections on the home. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

**about.vue**

```js
<template>
 <div>
  <router-link class="headers"
    :to="{name: 'home', hash: '#steps'}">
    Availability
  </router-link>
 </div>
</template>
```

and in your file which register [Vue-Router](https://router.vuejs.org/)

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...],
  scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (to.hash) {
      return {
        selector: to.hash
      }
    }
  }
});
```

more info -> [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html#async-scrolling)

Comment: When I click on the button it take me to this url http://localhost:3000/#steps which return as blank page.

Comment: it looks like you are using `hash` mode for  [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/), change it to `history` [more detail](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html), you may have to change some configs of your server [example-server-configurations](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)